# Removing/Adding block of code to HTML form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I have an HTML form with, at one point, 3 subsequent drop-down menu with option dinamically generated with DB queries. I would like to give the user the possibility to add/remove a set of these 3 menus so that they can set more than one value at a time, but I don't know how to structure the JavaScript code for the add/remove buttons. The HTML code of the form now looks like this:

```
<div id="valori">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <?php 
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", NULL) or die("Connection Failed");
        mysqli_select_db($con, "tag-it")or die("Connection Failed"); 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tipologie"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query); ?> 
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h4>Tipologia Prodotto:</h4>
            <select class="form-control" name="tipologia" onchange="listacampi(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" required>
            <option value="blank"></option>
            <?php while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?> 
            <option value="<?php echo $line['ID Tipologia'];?>"> <?php echo $line['Nome'];?> </option> 
            <?php } ?> 
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h4>Sotto-tipologia:</h4>
            <select class="form-control" name="campi" onchange="listavalori(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" required>
            <option value="blank"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h4>Valore:</h4>
            <input id="valoriAuto" name="valori" class="form-control" list="mylist" required>
            <datalist id="mylist">
            </datalist>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, the outer div has just been added because I think I could use it for the Javascript logic, the inner one with class row is a "set" of the three drop-down menus and the 3 most inner ones are the 3 drop down menus.
What I thought of was adding a button next to each set to remove the set itself, and add a new set with only a button to generate a new one. I don't think generating the set would be a big problem, because it's just a matter of creating the elements with the right php calls and appending them to the "set" div, but I wouldn't know how to remove them. I was thinking of using

```
document.getElementById("valori").removeChild()
```

But then I wouldn't know what to pass to removeChild, considering the fact that new sets would be generated by Javascript with an ID or name I couldn't predict, and that even by accessing the childNodes array I wouldn't know which one of the sets the user wanted to remove.

So, my question is: Is this approach going to work in any way? Is there a way to identify the "set" div element within the remove button and pass the object reference to the removeChild() function?

**EDIT:** I've been looking into the indexOf and splice functions, but they are not recognised as functions when called on element.children or element.ChildNodes. Don't they return arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to slightly modify the logic of what I'm going to do, so I'll post my answer in regard to that, but I'll also give an idea on how to solve the original problem.
What I'm doing now is having only one "remove" button regardless of the number of "sets" the user will create, and clicking the button will remove the last added set. What I do is:

```
<div>
    <input style="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('valori').removeChild(document.getElementById('valori').children[document.getElementById('valori').children.length-2])">
        <i class="fa fa-times">
            ::before
        </i>
    </input>
</div>
```

Notice the onclick function:

```
document.getElementById('valori').removeChild(document.getElementById('valori').children[document.getElementById('valori').children.length-2])
          ^This gets the outer div
                                 ^Calls the function
                                                                                                               ^the index will be the length of the children array-2, because the last child is the button itself
```

This will effectively remove the last added (or only, if that's the case) "set" div in the code.

---

Proposed solution for the original problem:

What I wanted to do initially was having a remove button for each "set" div, but I didn't have a way to pass an object reference when calling a function from the delete button because indexOf wouldn't work on the children or childNode arrays. I now have realized that what one could do is:

```
onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('valori').removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode)"
```